# Game window systems and internal frames

Tags: game-design, algorithm, rendering, graphics-programming

I don't know if this is a valid question, but: What kind of window manager do games use which have internal frames (Frames inside frames)? Does this differ between the programming languages (Are e.g. in Java the AWT/Swing libraries used to manage these and other graphical elements, such as buttons,or is this to restrictive (speed, graphical possibilities?))

A special example would be EVE Online, where the client can use the ingame windows like on a normal desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use Swing canvas as an opengl context where you can render your game. You can use all the classic Swing components **around** your game. I say around because you cannot add components inside your game, which is what you seems to ask for.

Games usally use what we call a *GUI* (for **G** raphical **U** ser **I** nterface). A GUI will just draw windows and other composents like you would draw a character in your game.

Here are two GUI's written in Java using *LWJGL* (OpenGL port in Java) for rendering:

- [TWL](http://twl.l33tlabs.org/)
- [Nifty GUI](http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/)

Since the above GUI's use OpenGL for rendering, you can render them in the OpenGL context of your game for example. A lot of others GUI's exist for many others languages and using differents technologies.

Comment: That's great! Thank you for the answer :)
I think major companies will use their own GUI-systems, so I don't want to start even thinking about programming my own 
(for now) :D